# Help for specific template

Tags: boxes, report

Im going to make a math and physics report in school, but before I need to fill a specific template in my report. It needs to look like the picture I added. I don't need to have the images above the boxes, but I need everything else. I have tried \framebox and \makebox, but im very new to latex and don't know a lot. Hope you would like to help!  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have so far ...

Comment: I haven't really wrote any of the code so far, because everything I have tried didn't look very good. I was hoping someone would share a package that could do these boxes. Im sorry

Comment: I would use a `tabularx{\textwidth}` environment for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}STADIERETNINGSOPGAVEN 2022\\ \\ SCT. KNUDS GIMNASIUM\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{9cm}|}{Dit navn og elevID}                                     &                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Fag i StudieRetningsOpgaven}                            & Vejledere                           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{text1}                                                  & text2                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{text3  }                                                  & text4                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{18cm}|}{\raggedright \lipsum[1-2] \rule{0pt}{44ex}   }                                                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. You have helped me a lot!:))

Comment: @Egelund48 You are welcome) here is some book with examples which You may like https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook